# How to update multiple related mongo db collections in one transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying to update multiple related mongodb collections at once.

**persons**

```
{"_id":1, "name":"jack",phone:"1234"}
```

**persondetails**

```
{"_id":1, "personid":1, "country":"Russia", lastvisitedon:"01/01/2010"}
{"_id":2, "personid":1, "country":"Canada", lastvisitedon:"01/01/2010"}
```

How can I update both `persons` and `persondetails` collection such that:

1. `person.name` is SET to "jack the reaper"
2. `persondetails.lastvisitedon` is SET to "01/01/2020" `WHERE personid=1 and  persondetails.country=Canada`

Transaction has to be atomic.

**The final result would look like :**

**persons**

```
 {"_id":1, "name":"jack the reaper",phone:"1234"}
```

**persondetails**

```
{"_id":1, "personid":1, "country":"Russia", lastvisitedon:"01/01/2010"}
{"_id":2, "personid":1, "country":"Canada", lastvisitedon:"01/01/2020"}
```

I am aware that one should avoid joins in mongodb but sometimes its unavoidable specially if `persondetails` could have HUGE no of related documents.

**Equivalent SQL query would be :**

```
update p
set p.name = "jack the reaper", pd.lastvisitedon="01/01/2020"
from persons p
    inner join persondetails pd on
        p._id = pd.personid 
        where p.phone = "1234" and pd.country="Canada"
```

I know from [MongoDb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) that multi collection transactions are possible now. But how do I solve the problem stated above?

**One naive approach that comes to mind is:**

```
Open transaction
 update persons collection where phone="1234"
 var personid= get _id from persons collection
 update persondetails collection where personid = personid and country = "canada"
Close transaction
```

What's the correct way of doing it in mongodb?

Comment: If you want to use a transaction, you can, although I see no reason why the two updates need to be in a transaction.

Comment: @D.SM because these two collections are related. The example is a bit naive sure. 
Let say they have to be atomic for some reason.